# jquery - replace text after modal has fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, reveal.js

I am trying to replace text via jquery in a modal.  My ".replace" piece works great in my console, when the modal is already visible and open, and the text "Change me" is displayed on the screen.  But, I can't get it to work without the text already being visible.   I believe we're using 'reveal'.  Any ideas?

The modal fires via a button click, if that helps.   A Timeout isn't ideal.

```
$("*").each(function () { 
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Change me", "I have been changed"));
    } 
});
}


<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" style="visibility: visible">
    <div class="my-modal-content">
        <div class="myText">Change me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show the code where you call the modal?

Comment: Thanks but not quite... the text I'm changing is not clicked.  It's shown by default in the modal, and I need to change upon the modal firing.

Comment: @Alex - I don't have visibility to that, unfortunately.  I believe it's done via knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for foundations inclusion of the reveal.js modal plugin [**here**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html#event-bindings)

From that page

> Previous versions of the reveal plugin emitted un-namespaced **open**, **opened**, **close** and **close**d events, however, these have been replaced by the namespaced **open.fndtn.reveal**, **opened.fndtn.reveal**, **close.fndtn.reveal** and **closed.fndtn.reveal** events. The un-namespaced events will be fully deprecated when Foundation 5.4 is released.

So depending on which version of reveal.js you're using, it looks like there are events you can hook into.

From that page, here's the snippet for hooking into the opened event:

```
$(document).on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    var newText = $('.myText').text().replace("Change me", "I have been changed");
    $('.myText').text(newText );

});
```

Edited to add--for older versions, i believe this is the way to hook into the event:

```
$('#myModal').bind('reveal:open', function () {
    var newText = $('.myText').text().replace("Change me", "I have been changed");
    $('.myText').text(newText );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Change me" would be `text` node `children` of `.myText` ? , or `false` at `if ($(this).children().length == 0)` ? Additionally , `$("*")` would select `html` and `body` elements , changing both `html` and `body` at call to `.text()` ?

Try

```js
$("body *").each(function () { 
    if ($(this).children(":contains('Change me')")) { 
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Change me", "I have been changed"));
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" style="visibility: visible">
<div class="my-modal-content">
<div class="myText">Change me</div>
<div class="myText">Do not change me</div>
</div>
</div>
```